# EventStore 3.0 and Publishing Events

Tags: event-sourcing, neventstore

So what would be the recommended way to publish events via Event Store 3.0?  Assuming I wire up the EventStore like this:

```
.UsingAsynchronousDispatchScheduler()
.DispatchTo(new DelegateMessageDispatcher(DispatchCommit))
```

where 'DispatchCommit' looks like this:

```
DispatchCommit(Commit commit)
```

I can watch the committed events fire off as expected.  However, ES 2.0 had the IContainer passing into the message dispatcher and I could resolve a bus instance and send events.  Shall I use a class that implements IDispatchCommits ?

Anyone using ES 3.0 with any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I'm using in production to dispatch commits: https://gist.github.com/1311195

I have my container configured to only create a single instance of the dependency.

Comment: Thanks. I ultimately went with a class that implements IDispatchCommits and uses an autofac module builder to inject the bus instance via a constructor.